# My <textarea> and everything after it appears to go past my div's background.

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="banner">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/front_end/nav_home.png" alt="Home" /></a><a href="portfolio.html"><img src="images/front_end/nav_portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio" /></a><a href="about.html"><img src="images/front_end/nav_about.png" alt="About" /></a><a     href="contact.html"><img src="images/front_end/nav_contact.png" alt="Contact" /></a>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="title">
Contact
</div>

<form id="emailform" method="POST" action="">
<label for="name">Name: </label><input class="inputs" type="text" name="name" />
<p><label for="email">Email: </label><input class="inputs" type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p><label for="phone">Phone: </label><input class="inputs" type="text" name="phone" /></p>
<p><label for="message">Your Message: </label><textarea id="largemessage" name="message"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message"/>
</form>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #111014;
background-image: url("images/front_end/bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#container {
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#banner {
margin-top: 45px;
margin-bottom: 38px;
height: 68px;
width: 1000px;
background-image: url("images/front_end/bannerbg.png");
}

#navigation {
height: 36px;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: 49px;
}

#content {
background-image: url("images/front_end/contentbg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: 100%;
width: 1000px;
padding-left:80px;
padding-right:60px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin-bottom: -8px;
}

#title {
height: 90px;
width: 542px;
padding-left: 60px;
padding-top: 36px;
background-image: url("images/front_end/titlebg.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 2.5em;
color: #dad8df;
margin-left: -80px;
}

#emailform {
color: #dad8df;
font-family: tahoma;
}

.inputs {
float: right;
margin-right: 675px;
width: 200px;
font: .9em tahoma;
}

#largemessage {
float: right;
clear: both;
margin-right: 175px;
width: 700px;
height: 150px;
resize: none;
font: .9em tahoma;
}

#submit {
margin-right: 175px;
clear: both;
float: right;
}
```

and a picture of what is happening:

A link to a picture of what is happening is here: [The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hq4u.png)

I realise i have really given you a heap of stuff to sort through but I have looked multiple times and just can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the textarea and submit button doesn't affect the height of the form is that they are floating.

You can use the `overflow` style to make the form contain floating elements also:

```
#emailform {
  color: #dad8df;
  font-family: tahoma;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

(What setting you use for `overflow` doesn't matter as you haven't specified a size for the element.)

Answer (score 2):

Give your "content" `<div>` the style `overflow: hidden;` and see if that helps.

Comment: Pointy is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/bWkW9/ with background set to orange instead of your image for testing.  Remove the overflow hidden to see the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

to the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag.

Comment: This could work, but it's nicer to just style the container properly.

Comment: Then you have to give the container a valued height.

Comment: No, @imoda, you don't, because by making it "overflow: hidden" you make it wrap around the "float" content.